# How does one extend the limit concept to extended real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Consider a function $f: \mathbb{R}\to [-\infty, + \infty]$. Is it possible to define

$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$$

where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ without appealing to a metric on $[-\infty, + \infty]$?

If yes, how?

Comment: It will critically depend on the topology. Generally, for a function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow X$ where $X$ is a topology space, we can define $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ as follows. For $a\in \mathbb R$ and $b\in X$, we say $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=b$ if for any open set $U$ that contains $b$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f((a-\delta,a)\cup(a,a+\delta))\subset U$.

Comment: @Calum Gilhooley You are right. I just want to say "limit" is a topology concept. I think your reference can give a perfect answer to OP's problem.  :)

Comment: This is close to what I was looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics)#Functions_on_topological_spaces. I wanted to find a statement that if $a$ is a non-isolated point of a topological space $X$, then the collection of punctured neighbourhoods of $a$ is a filter, $\mathscr{N}_a^*$, and if $f\colon X\to Y$ is a function, with $Y$ Hausdorff, then $f(\mathscr{N}_a^*)$ is a filter base, and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=b$ means $f(\mathscr{N}_a^*)$ is finer than the neighbourhood filter of $b$. But I couldn't find such a statement, and there are too many things I could have got wrong.

Comment: I asked a followup question: [Does any book now in print define the meaning of $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=b$ for $f\colon E\to Y$, $E\subseteq X$, $X$ a topological space, $Y$ Hausdorff?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3146911). To my great embarrassment, it was quickly pointed out that the answer is in Bourbaki! Schubert's definition seems to be closely based on that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eric Yau's comment goes straight to the point: the extended real line $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = [-\infty, +\infty]$ is a topological space, and it is common knowledge how to extend the definition of $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = b$ for functions $f \colon X \to Y$ between metric spaces to the case where $Y$ (and possibly also $X$) is a topological space on which a metric may not have been given.

An answer to the question can be assembled from the Wikipedia page [Limit of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function) [which incidentally needs some tidying up]:

> **Functions on topological spaces**
>
> Suppose $X,Y$ are topological spaces with $Y$ a Hausdorff space. Let $p$ be a limit point of $\Omega \subseteq X$, and $L \in Y$. For a function $f \colon \Omega \to Y$, it is said that the limit of $f$ as $x$ approaches $p$ is $L$ (i.e., $f(x) \to L$ as $x \to p$) and written
>   $$
> \lim_{x \to p}f(x) = L 
> $$
>   if the following property holds:
>
> - For every open neighborhood $V$ of $L$, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ such that $f(U \cap \Omega − {p}) \subseteq V$.
>
> This last part of the definition can also be phrased "there exists an open punctured neighbourhood $U$ of $p$ such that $f(U \cap \Omega) \subseteq V$".
>
> **Limits involving infinity**
>
> [...]
>
> - a neighborhood of $-\infty$ is defined to contain an interval $[-\infty,c)$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$,
> - a neighborhood of $\infty$ is defined to contain an interval $(c,\infty]$ where
>     $c\in\mathbb{R}$, and
> - a neighborhood of $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is defined in the normal way [for the] metric space $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> [...] $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is a topological space and any function of the form
>   $f\colon X\to Y$ with $X,Y\subseteq\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is subject to the topological
>   definition of a limit. Note that with this topological definition, it is easy to define infinite limits at finite points, which have not been defined above in the metric sense.

I said that this is "common knowledge", but it seems remarkably hard to find a clear statement of it in print! (One could always print out the Wikipedia page, I suppose!) :)

As indicated in my
comment, I thought that the definition of the
limit of a function between general topological spaces
might be buried somewhere in a discussion of filter convergence (or net
convergence); but I couldn't find it there, either (and I looked in
quite a number of books). I hope that someone can supply the lack of an
authoritative reference.

---

A clear general definition of the meaning of
$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = y$ can be given by condensing extracts from
pages 48--62 of Horst Schubert, *Topology* (Macdonald 1968):

> A non-empty system $\mathscr{B}$ of subsets of the set $X$ is called
>   a *filter basis* (on $X$) if the following conditions are satisfied:
>
> **FB 1** The intersection of two sets from $\mathscr{B}$
>   contains a set from $\mathscr{B}$.
>
> **FB 2** The empty set does not belong to $\mathscr{B}$.
>
> A non-empty system $\mathscr{F}$ of subsets of the set $X$ is called
>   a *filter* (on $X$) if the following conditions are satisfied:
>
> **F 1** Every superset of a set from $\mathscr{F}$ belongs to $\mathscr{F}$.
>
> **F 2** The intersection of two sets from $\mathscr{F}$ belongs to $\mathscr{F}$.
>
> **F 3** The empty set does not belong to $\mathscr{F}$.
>
> The neighbourhoods of a point $x$ form a filter, the
>   *neighbourhood filter* of $x$. Every filter basis $\mathscr{B}$
>   on $X$ determines a filter $\mathscr{F}$ on $X$.
>
> Let $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{G}$ be two filters on the set $X$.
>   If every set of $\mathscr{F}$ belongs to $\mathscr{G}$, then
>   $\mathscr{F}$ is said to be *coarser* than $\mathscr{G}$ and
>   $\mathscr{G}$ *finer* than $\mathscr{F}$.
>
> Let $X$ be a topological space. A filter $\mathscr{F}$ on $X$ is
>   said to be *convergent* to a point $x$ if $\mathscr{F}$ is
>   finer than the neighbourhood filter of $x$. If $\mathscr{F}$
>   converges to $x$ then $x$ is called a *limit* of $\mathscr{F}$
>   and one writes $\mathscr{F} \to x$ or $x \in \lim \mathscr{F}$. One
>   says that $x = \lim \mathscr{F}$ if $x$ is the only limit of
>   $\mathscr{F}$. A filter basis $\mathscr{B}$ is said to be
>   convergent to $x$ if the filter with the basis $\mathscr{B}$
>   converges to $x$.
>
> Let $X$ be a topological space.  The following assertions are
>   equivalent:
>
> **H** Every two distinct points of $X$ have distinct
>   neighbourhoods.
>
> **H$'$** Every point of $X$ is the intersection of its closed
>   neighbourhoods.
>
> **H$''$** The diagonal of $X \times X$ is closed.
>
> **H$'''$** There exists no filter on $X$ that converges to two
>   different points.
>
> A topological space $X$ is said to be *Hausdorff* or *separated*
>   if it satisfies one (and hence all) of these conditions.
>
> Let $f \colon X \to X'$ be a mapping [function] and $\mathscr{F}$ a
>   filter on $X$. The filter on $X'$ that has images of the sets from
>   $\mathscr{F}$ as a basis is called the *image* of $\mathscr{F}$
>   relative to $f$ and will be denoted by $f(\mathscr{F})$.
>
> If $\mathscr{B}'$ is a filter basis on $X'$, then the inverse image
>   of sets from $\mathscr{B}'$ relative to $f$ satisfy condition
>   **FB 1**. Condition **FB 2** is satisfied if and only if
>   no set from $\mathscr{B}'$ has an empty inverse image.
>
> If $\mathscr{F}'$ is a filter on $X'$ and the inverse
>   images of sets from $\mathscr{F}'$ are non-empty, then these images
>   form, in general, only a filter basis.
>
> Let $f \colon X \to X'$ be a mapping and $\mathscr{F}'$ a filter on
>   $X'$. If the inverse images of sets from $\mathscr{F}'$ form a
>   filter basis on $X$, then the filter with this basis is called the
>   *inverse image* of $\mathscr{F}'$ relative to $f$ and will be
>   denoted by $f^{-1}(\mathscr{F}')$.
>
> Let $\mathscr{B}'$ be a filter basis on $X'$. The filter
>   $\mathscr{F}'$ with basis $\mathscr{B}'$ has an inverse image
>   relative to the mapping $f \colon X \to X'$ if and only if no set
>   from $\mathscr{B}'$ has an empty inverse image.
>
> The following important special case is covered by these
>   considerations. Let $A$ be a subset of $X$. Relative to the
>   inclusion of $A$ in $X$ every filter $\mathscr{G}$ on $A$ has an
>   image on $X$ which in this case is called the *extension* of
>   $\mathscr{G}$ to $X$. If $\mathscr{F}$ is a filter on $X$, then the
>   inverse image of $\mathscr{F}$, relative to the inclusion of $A$ in
>   $X$, need not exist. It exists if and only if $A$ meets every set
>   from $\mathscr{F}$. This inverse image is also called the
>   *trace* of $\mathscr{F}$ on $A$.
>
> We introduce some more terminology and assume for this purpose that
>   $Y$ is Hausdorff. The continuity of the mapping $f \colon X \to Y$
>   at the point $x_0$ is equivalent to
>   $$
> \lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0),
> $$
>   which asserts that the image of the neighbourhood filter of $x_0$
>   converges to $f(x_0)$. If the neighbourhood filter of $x_0$ induces
>   a filter $\mathscr{F}$ on a subset $A$ of $X$ [it is clear that by
>   this form of words he means that $\mathscr{F}$ has a trace on $A$],
>   then we write
>   $$
> \lim_{\substack{x\to x_0\\x\in A}} f(x) = y,
> $$
>   when the image of $\mathscr{F}$ relative to the mapping $f|_A$
>   converges to $y$. If in particular $A = X \setminus \{x_0\}$, then
>   we will also write
>   $$
> \lim_{\substack{x\to x_0\\x\ne x_0}} f(x) = y.
> $$
>   [It is clear that this notation is defined if and only if $x_0$ is
>   not an isolated point of $X$; and then $\mathscr{F}$ is the
>   collection of all punctured neighbourhoods of $x_0$ in $X$.]

Comment: The nearest thing to a clear statement of the general definition, in print, that I have found so far is on page 45 of A. Froelicher and W. Bucher, *Calculus in Vector Spaces without Norm*, Lecture Notes in Mathematics **30**, Springer 1966; but even there, the meaning of $\lim_{\chi\to0}q(\chi)=a$ is only defined in the case where $q:\mathbb{R}\to{E}$ satisfies $q(0)=a$, i.e. the notation is only used as another way of saying that $q$ is continuous at $0$.